# Two finger scroll not working on a Samsung RV510

Tags: touchpad

The touchpad on my samsung rv510 doesn't let me use two finger scroll on Ubuntu. I'm very new to using Linux so could you please give me instructions that you would give to a child. I've tried various terminal commands etc that other people have suggested but I can't seem to get it working. Any help with be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried going to the touchpad settings? If not, go to the settings menu and select the Mouse option. Then navigate to the Touchpad tab where it should have the option.

Hope it helps!